# Creating an executable jar with maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies

I am trying to create a jar in maven with dependencies. I am very new to maven, and I know there's very similar questions but none of their answers have worked and I need this jar soon. The program has no problems running on it's own in intellij, but when I run the jar file, I keep coming across this error:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory

Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main"

I have tried to use maven-shade-plugin, but it seems to have had no effect.
here is my pom.xml:

```
<groupId>com.company</groupId>
<artifactId>physicsEngine</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are you executing `package` from within IntelliJ?  It sounds like that GSON dependency is not making it into your JAR.

Comment: I run main.java from within intellij(which works fine). And yes I think that gson doesn't make it into the jar as well, but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: I bailed out.  Hopefully someone else can fix your problem +1.

Comment: Have you checked if the jar really contains all the required classes?

Comment: I renamed the created jar to a zip to see it's contense (command line wasn't working). There were 3 folders : com.company with all my .class files, levels with 2 Json files, and META-INF my manifest file. There was no sign of gson. Also when I try to run the file it gives an error saying it is corrupt.

Comment: what maven's goal do you use to create the jar project? Are you using maven plugins inside intellij or are you using maven on console log? Are you sure that the java version of your project is the same of the compiler?